# Android, ScrollView not scrolling past certain point, not showing all views / content

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I've looked at all the similar questions for this and I can't find a workable answer. I have a ScrollView with a child LinearLayout and several child TextViews. The ScrollView stops scrolling at about TextView #10. I have no idea why it would do that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff7c2b"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 1!"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 2!"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 3!"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 4!"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 5!"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 6!"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 7!"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 8!"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 9!"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 10!"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 11!"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 12!"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 13!"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 14!"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**The main layout that the fragment layout is being added to:**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="!!!!!!!!!!!" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/gallery2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click to see..."
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:textColor="#377bff" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <TableRow>

            <ToggleButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New ToggleButton"
                android:textOff="show fragment"
                android:textOn="hide fragment"
                android:id="@+id/toggleButton" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="New Activity"
                    android:id="@+id/newactivitybutton"/>

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try "fill_parent" for the scrollview's height.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that already. It still doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: Also to note, this is being inflated inside a fragment. I'm not sure if that in any way would affect the scrollview behavior though.

Comment: Can you also show the layout for the activity into which the fragment gets attached?

Comment: The inflation within the fragment should be a problem but link the xml just incase because I'm puzzled why it doesn't work. Is the testing done within an emulator? What other meta data can you give us about the issue

Comment: I just added the layout that the fragment layout is being added to for further context.

Comment: Yes I'm testing in an emulator.

Comment: It's not showing a fixed number of textViews, 3 at the bottom. So if I keep adding textViews it shows the added content, again just not the 3 at the bottom. I've tried playing with the margin settings and even completely removing them. That had no effect.

Comment: I basically misdiagnosed the problem. I assumed it wasn't scrolling past a point when rather it wasn't showing a chunk of the LinearLayout at the bottom. That's still a problem, but not as severe. If anyone could help me with this issue still though, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use these below layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#ff7c2b"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 1!"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 2!"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 3!"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 4!"
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 5!"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 6!"
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 7!"
                android:id="@+id/textView7"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 8!"
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 9!"
                android:id="@+id/textView9"

                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 10!"
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 11!"
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 12!"
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 13!"
                android:id="@+id/textView13"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="This is textView 14!"
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:background="#00BBFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```